# Simple PowerShell Script, to obtain PATHS from a CSV, confirm that those exist and write another CSV with the true results

Tags: powershell, csv

I´m new to this for and I´m also starting with PowerShell, and after trying several things I need help from you. In a simple thing.

I'm trying to import a .csv with a list of files/paths, and then confirm that those routes exist on the hard drive. Then when I get the result, I need to export the results of the found paths back to .csv
I have this CSV in c:\temp\original.csv with this data:

```
Path
C:\temp\1.txt
C:\temp\2.txt
C:\temp\3.txt
C:\temp\4.txt
C:\temp\5.txt
C:\temp\6.txt
```

I have these files 1.txt and 3.txt and 5.txt. I created this code, but all the results return "False".:

```
$data=import-csv "c:\temp\original.csv"
foreach ($path in $data) {
test-Path -path $path | Write-Host }
```

When I use the following code, the file paths appear, so I think it is keeping the csv data well:

```
$data=import-csv "c:\temp\original.csv"
foreach ($path in $data) {
Write-Host test-Path -path $path }
```

I do this and if it shows the file as true:

```
Test-Path -Path C:\temp\1.txt
```

Could you help me finish the script to get the correct data and that the actual results export them to a CSV?

How should I make the results "true" export them to a .CSV and delete the files in their location? I have a list of 30000 files that I need to check that have been deleted by another process, but I want to save the list of those that still exist and that these will be permanently erased. Thank you very much, really.

I really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

A greeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source data I started with. Thanks for editing the question.

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\original.csv
Path
C:\temp\1.txt
C:\temp\2.txt
C:\temp\3.txt
C:\temp\4.txt
C:\temp\5.txt
C:\temp\6.txt
```

The code imports the .csv file, then creates an object with the `path` field and and expression indicating whether or not the file exists.

```
Import-Csv -Path '.\original.csv' |
    Select-Object -Property path, @{Name="exists";Expression={Test-Path -Path $_.path}} |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\original2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This resulted in the following output.

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\original2.csv
"path","exists"
"C:\temp\1.txt","True"
"C:\temp\2.txt","True"
"C:\temp\3.txt","True"
"C:\temp\4.txt","False"
"C:\temp\5.txt","True"
"C:\temp\6.txt","True"
```

**Edit:**

This code will delete the file that exists and put the name into an output .csv log file. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

```
Import-Csv -Path '.\original.csv' |
    Where-Object { Test-Path $_.Path } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-Item -Path $_.Path -WhatIf
        $_
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\original2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. @lit, you have answered all my questions in a simple code, you have solved my problem !!!.
I thank you very very much. My best wishes!
A greeting.